# can a fb user send an apprequest to all friends same day no matter how many?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

Hi am using this function that works by a single ID (`52000121`) and comma separatted ID's (`5000000,500002,500004,000002001`)

```
function invite(id) {

        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: '<?=get_texto_clave('wants_you_to_join')?>',
          title: '<?=get_texto_clave('send_app_request')?> <?=$_SESSION['alias']?>',
          to: id, 
        }, function(response){
            if(response!=null){
                var invitados = id.split(',');
                for( i=0; i<invitados.length; i++){
                     $('#friend_'+invitados[i]).addClass('invited');
                     $('#friend_'+invitados[i]+' .inviteButton').addClass('invitedBtn').text('<?=get_texto_clave('Invitado')?>');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Wich seems to be working fine,

But I have just sent more than 500 invites to friends of mine, and they all got the 'ivited' class (When i completed the popup);

¿Did they all recived it?

I know the response debugging could be better, but still would like to know if user can send an invite to all of his friends same day no matter how many friends are. Or is there any user/app limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a no limit to the app requests you send

But if you use multi friend selector, you can select maximum of 50 and 25 in IE.

Naturally, if you're being spammy, you'll still get reported a lot and automated systems could block you, so remember to keep to a reasonable volume of requests.

> Btw, You can read the response to know to whom it was delivered.